# Assistance with SQL ADD Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried looking online for this query to see if its possible but can't seem to find anything. I am creating a webpage for which I want a user to enter an amount and click confirm when they click confirm it will add the amount they put in to the existing amount in an SQL row, is this possible?

below is what I want to happen

```
Amount in SQL = 1000
user amount = 100
new amount in SQL = £1100
```

Cheers, hope this makes sense.

Comment: Do you have some code? What technology do you use to communicate with the database? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using a table named amount that has id, firstname, lastname and amount. It will done via PHP, the user will be shown a list of names held and add an amount to that users amount.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a MySQL table:

```
"UPDATE `amount` SET `amount` = `amount`.amount + $newAmount WHERE (condition) LIMIT 1"
```

All you would need to do is set the variable $newAmount before the query to the value you want added. In the (condition) part you could use for example `name='$name'`